# Why \markboth command doesn't work in my overleaf?

Tags: latex, overleaf, ieee, conference

I am preparing my conference paper and the conference committee provies a template in a word documents. But, I am comfortable with Latex. I am using Overleaf. In the template at the very beginning the conference name should be included in 2 line like this figure. [image]

I found many blogs and they suggested to use `/markboth`. But this command is not working in my used template.

My Code:

```
\documentclass[conference, a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}


\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\input{authorInfo}


\maketitle

% ========Header and Pub Id=======
\markboth{IEEE Transactions on Evolutionary Computation}{AA}

\IEEEpubid{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\ \\[150pt] \raggedright
  979-8-3503-5901-5/23/\$31.00 ©2023 IEEE 
\end{minipage}}
% =============
```

Please suggest me some ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to solve this problem with /markboth but I failed. However, Overleaf's documentation says:

> Headers and footers produced by [fancyhdr](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Headers_and_footers#Multi-line_headers_or_footers) can contain multiple lines.

So, if you want to solve it with fncyhdr, you can use it like this in your code:

```
\documentclass[conference, a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %load fancyhdr package

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\input{authorInfo}

\pagestyle{fancy} % set pagestyle to fancy
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  %delete decorative lines under header
\fancyhead[L]{2023 26th International Conference on Computer and Information Technology (ICCIT)\\13-15 December 2023, Cox's Bazar, Bangladesh } %define header

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{fancy} %\maketitle defines the current page style as plain so you should readjust the page style after \maketitle to make the header appear on the first page as well

% ========Header and Pub Id=======
\markboth{IEEE Transactions on Evolutionary Computation}{AA}

\IEEEpubid{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\ \\[150pt] \raggedright
  979-8-3503-5901-5/23/\$31.00 ©2023 IEEE 
\end{minipage}}
% =============

\end{document}
```